# Scrapyd permissions 'nogroup' error

Tags: python, ubuntu, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd

I've been struggling with the Scrapyd installation for some time, and even though in the end I seem to have managed, I still have some problems.

I am getting an error when processing of items.

`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/project/pipelines.py", line 33, in process_item
OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database`

In the `/var/lib/scrapyd/dbs` there's the project's database that has no write permission for the group, but all the scrapyd files and folders there are `scrapy nogroup` and have no permissions.
How can i make it work without changing everything individually, so that it works with new projects too.

Comment: try this `sudo chmod -R a+w /var/lib/scrapyd/dbs/`